# See IMDb, Rotten Tomatoes, Metacritic ratings together

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there some web app where I can see IMDb, Rotten Tomatoes and Metacritic movie ratings together?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firefox there is this extension called [CineMeter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cinemeter/) available

> Compare Movie Ratings. IMDB, RottenTomatoes, MetaCritic and
>   MovieWeb.com

For Chrome you could try out [Filme Info and Reviews](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/miajgoaiekedkmjfheebgfgcmjmkphhk?hl=en-GB)

> Everybody has their own favorite sites to check the information or
>   find reviews about an upcoming, recent or old movie. This extension
>   helps you save your time by loading all your favorite sites in a
>   single click.
>
> Currently 10 sites are supported:
>
> 1. IMDB
> 2. Wikipedia
> 3. RottenTomatoes
> 4. Roger Ebert @ suntimes.com
> 5. Flixster
> 6. Allrovi
> 7. Metacritic
> 8. Netflix
> 9. BoxOfficeMojo
> 10. MovieReviews

Comment: +1 Thanks for the suggestion. But I mostly use Chromium :(

Comment: @BernhardHeijstek: Updated with some Chrome goodness! :)

Comment: Thanks again, but the Chrome extension does only a Google 'I am Feeling Lucky' and opens each site in a new tab. It still doesn't show the ratings together.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather not use a browser extension, check out [MovieAggregator](http://movieaggregator.com/).  It's a simple web app that lets you search for a movie.  The results give you ratings and links from:

- IMDB
- Netflix
- RottenTomatoes
- iTunes
- TheMovieDB
- Amazon.

It also includes a movie poster, summary, major cast list, and embedded trailer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me; I put in that initial answer from my iPhone.